# Review these link-lacking answers!

Tags: discussion, answers, answer-quality

I downloaded all of our posts through the API, and I noticed something disturbing: 28 of our answers don't contain links.

Almost all answers here should have a link of some sort - why else would you post it? So, without further ado, here's the list.

- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/59 [added a link]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/158 [Built in solution]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/192 [added a link]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/306 [Fractaliste: added a link]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/323 [added a link]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/348 [Nick-Wilde: doesn't need a link as talking about built in OS dependent option]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/351 [Links to discussed recommendations are in the question]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/390 [Nick-Wilde: edited & commented]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/459 [added a link]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/467 [aman207: added link]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/518 [Nick-Wilde: edited & commented]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/524 [Solution uses built in functionality]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/618 [aman207: edited]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/648 [aman207: edited & commented]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/675 [added a link]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/691 [aman207: added link]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/720 [aman207: added link]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/734 [Nick-Wilde: No link needed; but a nothing available type answer]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/741 [added a link]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/742 [aman207: added a link]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/831 [added a link]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/856 [added a link]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/965 [Flagged as NAA]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/998 [aman207: added link]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1009 [Fractaliste: added a link]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1083 [added link - aman207]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1097 [Flagged as NAA]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1262 [Solution uses built in functionality]

It would be great if people could go through and leave comments asking the author to add a link to the software. If it's very obvious, you can also add the link yourself.

Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Half a dozen of us went through the list and added links pretty much everywhere (except a couple which we flagged as non-answers).

Thanks to everybody who participated.